# Use SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider with some predefined terms?

Tags: android, search, autocomplete

I'm looking for some information on extending SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider such that it will handle two types of suggestions:

- User search history
- Predefined terms that I'd like to always have as possible suggestions

For example, when a user starts typing "Goo", maybe they've searched for "Goo Gone" before - and maybe I'd also like to include "Google" since it's in my list of "special terms".

Referring to the documentation at [Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) I see that I can really do an either or - use Google's code or roll my own SQLite database to store things. Is there a way to override part of SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can extend SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider with your own class. This is the class I wrote to do this: https://github.com/bostonbusmap/bostonbusmap/blob/master/src/boston/Bus/Map/provider/TransitContentProvider.java

```
package boston.Bus.Map.provider;

import boston.Bus.Map.data.RoutePool;
import boston.Bus.Map.main.Main;
import boston.Bus.Map.provider.DatabaseContentProvider.DatabaseAgent;
import boston.Bus.Map.transit.TransitSystem;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;

public class TransitContentProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

    private UriMatcher matcher;

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.bostonbusmap.transitprovider";
    public static final int MODE = SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;


    private static final int SUGGESTIONS_CODE = 5;

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

    public TransitContentProvider()
    {
        matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SUGGESTIONS_CODE);
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        boolean create = super.onCreate();
        return create;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
    {
        int code = matcher.match(uri);
        switch (code)
        {
        case SUGGESTIONS_CODE:
            if (selectionArgs == null || selectionArgs.length == 0 || selectionArgs[0].trim().length() == 0)
            {
                return super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            }
            else
            {
                ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
                return DatabaseAgent.getCursorForSearch(resolver, selectionArgs[0]);
            }
        default:
            return super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I was apprehensive since I saw in several parts of javadoc that I shouldn't be overriding that class. I'll give it a try and then mark you as correct after I get it going.

Comment: What does the setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE) method look like?