# Android SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider query limit

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm working with search suggestion framework and here is the case. I get some query string and make query from content resolver, but problem is that I can't limit the results. Found several solutions but they dont work for me.

My content provider is extending SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider and declared in manifest, here query uri

`Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/search_suggest_query");`

sol 1:
adding query parameter to uri

`SearchSuggestionProvider.URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT, String.valueOf(5)).build()`

sol 2: 
adding limit in sortOrder query parameter

`getContentResolver().query(URI, null, "?", new String[]{searchQuery}, "_id asc limit 5");`

In both cases query returns all rows from search suggestions. Does anyone know how to limit such a query?

Comment: SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT Query parameter added to suggestion queries to limit the number of suggestions returned. **This limit is only advisory and suggestion providers may chose to ignore it**.

Comment: There is a better solution, a completely different way, I added the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the query method in the base class SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider in the framework

```
/**
     * This method is provided for use by the ContentResolver.  Do not override, or directly
     * call from your own code.
     */
    // TODO: Confirm no injection attacks here, or rewrite.
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, 
            String sortOrder) {
```

Potentially you can override it and implement the limiting - but as you can see the comment above it clear states "do not override". 
In the existing method no limiting is enforced.

However I see in some of the other answers on stack-overflow and other sites that people do override it.

Example : 
[Use SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider with some predefined terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026100/use-searchrecentsuggestionsprovider-with-some-predefined-terms)

Based on this I think you can try it out - override the query method and add your own implementation which supports limiting the results. Parse the `SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT` that you have used in the query method and use it to limit the results returned.

Comment: "use this limit when actually querying the database or whatever your data source is" This question is related to SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider specifically. Please be more specific on how to override `query` for this case.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question initially. Added more specific details now.

Comment: There is a better solution on a completely different way, I added the answer below

Answer (score 5):

Actually, we were searching in the wrong place.
After all this investigations, finally I found the trick.

On the results screen (Where we save the query to the search SearchRecentSuggestions) we call this method

```
SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(this,
                    SearchSuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, SearchSuggestionProvider.MODE);
suggestions.saveRecentQuery(query, null);
```

[SearchRecentSuggestions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/SearchRecentSuggestions.html) was the responsible to save this query to the content provider.

This class has a protected method called `truncateHistory()` with this documentation

> Reduces the length of the history table, to prevent it from growing
>   too large.

So the solution is simply, create a custom class, override this method, and call the super implementation with the required limit.

Here is the example

```
public class SearchRecentSuggestionsLimited extends SearchRecentSuggestions {

    private int limit;

    public SearchRecentSuggestionsLimited(Context context, String authority, int mode, int limit) {
        super(context, authority, mode);
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    protected void truncateHistory(ContentResolver cr, int maxEntries) {
        super.truncateHistory(cr, limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I understood right, that will limit whole table size, but what I was asking is  how to limit query rows amount? or your solution won't affect table size?

Comment: Yes, it affects the table size, but still save the top 5 recent. By reducing the table size to 5 will affect the query rows. But if you want to have an option like show more history query, this will not help you.